# RegEx ignore a match if a whole word is anywhere in the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation

Hi Im trying to get a RegEx to work.  I have this text:

```
/Ffont2 45.83 Tf  252 980 Td (XX7445 DDA PURCHASE 05/28 04:48
MCDONALD'S F561 CHICAGO IL 105/29          10.25) Tj ET
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 RG BT /Ffont2 45.83 Tf  252 937 Td (   12333378 214904443) Tj ET
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 RG BT /Ffont2 45.83 Tf  252 894 Td (CITI CARD ONLINE PAYMENT 12345678                    05/29          87.99) Tj ET
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 rg 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 RG BT /Ffont2 45.83 Tf  252 851 Td (XX7445 DDA PURCHASE 0528 14:11 #03632 JEWEL CHICAGO IL     0529          97.60) Tj ET
```

and Im trying to get everything from `Td` to `Tj`  like

```
Td (CITI CARD ONLINE PAYMENT 12345678                    05/29                87.99) Tj
```

but I want to skip things if they have no date, (must have forward slash), they must have a money amount(must have period) and I dont want it if it has the word "purchase" in it. So

```
Td (XX7445 DDA PURCHASE 0528 14:11 #03632 JEWEL CHICAGO IL     0529         97.60) Tj
```

would not be returned.  right now I have

```
(Td \()([^\)]*)([^\)]*)([/][^\)]*[.][^\)]*\) Tj)
```

for my regex and that gets everything but it gets it even it has "purchase"

Comment: I do hope that isn't a real card number + expiry..

Comment: (Td \([^\)]*[/][^\)]*[.][^\)]*\) Tj)

Comment: I've reformatted the text, please check if it's correct like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine. Regex *can* be used for this.. but why <s>put a Formula 1 car on a go-kart track</s> (<--- bad analogy..) waste CPU cycles?

```
var matchesWithoutPurchase = Regex.Matches(yourInput, @"(Td \()([^\)]*)([^\)]*)([/][^\)]*[.][^\)]*\) Tj)")
    .Cast<Match>().Where(x => !x.Value.ToLower().Contains("purchase"));

foreach (var match in matchesWithoutPurchase) {
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Regex negative lookarounds are overkill for this.

Comment: thanks!  I know I dont need to use the regex for that, but there was so much code after the regex already and im worried about that, i thought i could use the regex if i could.  And also for future reference I wanted to learn a godo way.  but thanks this is good too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex to ensure that your match doesn't contain the word 'PURCHASE', you could use a negative look-ahead such as the following:

```
@"(?![^\)]*PURCHASE)(Td \()([^\)]*)([^\)]*)([/][^\)]*[.][^\)]*\) Tj)"
```

The look-ahead prevents a match if the word 'PURCHASE' appears before the next `)`.

If you want to prevent 'purchase' also, you could add `(?i)` to the start of the regex, or add the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag as the last argument to the `Regex` method call.

Looking closer at your regex I notice that the second `([^\)]*)` is redundant as everything that it matches will be captured by the `([^\)]*)` immediately preceding it.

It also seems strange that your are capturing `(Td \()` - the capture will always be `Td (`, so why bother?  And the second capture will start with `/` and end with `Tj)` - is that what you intended?

I assume you know that you could replace the `[/]` with `\/`, and `[.]` with `\.`.

Anyway, to just capture what is inside the brackets, you could use:

```
@"(?![^\)]*PURCHASE)Td \(([^\)]*\/[^\)]*\.[^\)]*)\) Tj";
```

Comment: thanks.  the regex i pasted was after messing with it to get the negative lookahead working and is not really what i was doing.  The capture group in the beginning is just something i added when i was frsutrated.  Thanks for your solution though.  This was kind of a home project and Im at work now, Im excited to try when I get off work tonight.